# Removing Spaces in Calculated Lists

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a calculated column which creates a URL which calls a Column called "Pitch Name" and from that will create the URL but I have to remove the space/spaces between words from pitch which needs to be displayed as a URL. Example of this is "Coca Cola" needs to be "CocaCola" so the site name can be"http://sitename.com/CocaCola". I've tried using the TRIM function but that doesn't work. I have tried the REPLACE function aswell but that seems not to work either. Any Solutions?

(Taken from an attempt to edit an answer:) 
**Update:** The REPLACE and FIND Functions work but only if the string contains the amount of the desired character. And if the character doesn't appear the same amount of times the formula has asked for you will always get the string #VALUE which means it hasn't worked

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Calculated Fields use Excel functions, not .NET functions, so you probably want to use [SUBSTITUTE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/substitute-function-HP010062578.aspx) rather than REPLACE.

Try something like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE([Pitch Name], " ", "")
```

**Update:**

According to Xue-Mei Chang in [Calculated Field Error](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/5487889f-5fc8-48e1-8ea2-28f8c9c8ad0c):

> The "SUBSTITUTE" function is not available in SharePoint.

As a workaround, he proposes:

> For the "SUBSTITUTE" function, you have to use a combination of the "REPLACE" function with a "FIND" function. The "FIND" would return the position of the desired character in the string, which would then pass on to the "REPLACE" function so it can replace it with the new character.

Comment: In Sharepoint 2010 the SUBSTITUTE formula has been removed which is the biggest pain in the world as that's the one i need